# Executing a PHP script from an android application or in java

Tags: java, php, android, notifications

I've tried my best not to ask this question as a similar question was previously asked, however, the solution remains unclear.

I currently have a PHP script which when executed sends a notification to all users in the database.

This script is stored in localhost http://192.168.0.20/fcm/push_notification.php

This is the script:

```
<?php 
function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = AIzaSyDYzkdd3aPZtgg4VkZQkLu7vombVecin4M',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","fcm");
$sql = " Select Token From users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$tokens = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
$message = array("message" => " Welcome to Remi.");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status;
 ?>
```

After running the PHP script:
{"multicast_id":6897135459617096033,"success":5,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1492104139267823%345aa993f9fd7ecd"}, etc}"

It successfully sends "Welcome to Remi." text to all devices.

Now here's the problem: I've been trying to make a simple Android application where when you click a button, it will execute the PHP script to hopefully send a notification to all the devices in the database.

The PHP side is done, but im having troubles launching the PHP script from android/java. I'm not sure how to do this; I've looked at multiple possible solutions but still fail to understand how to solve this issue.

Here is my java code to try and launch the PHP script:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView myBrowser;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);
    Button create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
               launchPHP();
               launchPHP2();

            } catch (Exception e){
                //
            }

           //myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
           //assert myBrowser != null;
           //myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/reminder.htaccess");



        }
    });

}
private void launchPHP() throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.20/fcm/push_notification.php/");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
private void launchPHP2() throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.20/fcm/push_notification.php/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    } else {
        InputStream err = conn.getErrorStream();
    }
}

}
```

Is there a possible solution to execute the PHP script from an Android java application?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: `im having troubles launching the PHP script from android/java. `. Yes. Indeed. And i can see which troubles you have with that code. But if you are not even telling which troubles and what happens instead...

Comment: Oh sorry,  the java code is my attempt at trying to find and execute the PHP script from java. I've tried a few methods but they don't really do anything. There's no error when ran either. Clicking the button does nothing, and I'm unsure what I'm missing in my code (or if even if this is the right approach)

Comment: It will crash your app immediately.  And you should place a Toast() in that catch block otherwise the user does not know about an ioexception. But your app crashes now.. And if not then you use the wrong button.